# getting TestNG to treat class variables like JUnit with Guice

Tags: java, junit, testng, guice

I am trying to setup TestNG so that it gives me new instances of my class variable for each test (basically like JUnit). I need this as I intend to parallelize my tests at the method level. I have been experimenting with both standalone Guice and the built in Guice functionality that TestNG provides to try to accomplish this but I have had no luck. I know that I can use ThreadLocal, but calling .get() for every variable in the test is pretty unappealing. I am weary of using GuiceBerry as it does not really have a lot of updates/activity and it's last release is not even acquirable via Maven. I am pretty set on TestNG as for all the inconvenience this is causing me it still does a lot of great things. I am open to things other tools though to accomplish my goal. Basically I want things setup so the below tests would work consistently. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
// just has a variable thats a class called child with a simple string variable
// with a value of "original
Parent p;

@Test
public void sometest1(){
    p.child.value = "Altered";
    Assert.assertTrue(p.child.value.equals("Altered"));

}

@Test
public void sometest2(){
    Assert.assertTrue(p.child.value.equals("original"));
}
```

Comment: The Before method would not solve the problem, all it would do is alter the classes instance of the variable. Any variable created there will not persist into the test

Comment: There is also `@BeforeClass`...

Answer (score 0):

TestNG doesn't create a new instance for each test. If you want such a behavior than I recommend creating separate test classes. e.g.:

```
public class SomeTest1 {
    Parent p;

    @Test
    public void something(){
        p.child.value = "Altered";
        Assert.assertTrue(p.child.value.equals("Altered"));
    }
}

public class SomeTest2 {
    Parent p;

    @Test
    public void something(){
        Assert.assertTrue(p.child.value.equals("original"));
    }
}
```

Note that [TestNG can run JUnit 3 and JUnit 4 tests](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#junit) (you might maintain a mixed suite depending on the style you want to use in a given test class).